# Trouble with paragraphs floating w/ only some text having border

Tags: html, css

I'm having trouble created the image shown in "image link". I tried making it a list with custom bullets but they push the boxes to the left of it while also not showing the image.

I am thinking of making the boxes as separate paragraphs each with a border and then floating them next to the text w/out a border. But I have no clue how to actually do this.

As you can see in the second link- I'm trying to add the list on the right of two other elements - if that changes anything.

[Image link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YxWbf.png)
[what I've already done](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MqfZz.png)

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) with your code, so we can help you out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know how your code looks, but I think this is what you're looking for, no? You can obviously change the colors to something similar like in the image you provided, if that's what you want.

```css
.box {
  text-align:center;
  border:1px solid black;
  width:50px;
  height:40px;
  padding-top:10px;
  float:left;
}

.label {
float:left;
  padding-top:15px;
  padding-left:5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">MAR<br/>12</div>
<label class="label">Spring Break</label>
<br style="line-height:70px;"/>
<div class="box">APR<br/>27</div>
<label class="label">Last Day of Spring Classes</label>
<br style="line-height:70px;"/>
<div class="box">APR<br/>30</div>
<label class="label">Final Exam Week</label>
```

Comment: That worked really great thank you so much. Would you mind helping me out with one more thing?

Comment: @Adrianna Not at all, what's the issue!?

Comment: Okay so when I added the code you supplied the text in a different div above your coding were suddenly squished. I added all the coding for the two groups (which is a lot). I was wondering if you could see the reason for this happening?

Comment: @Adrianna The css code in `.container_two` is causing it, not the code I provided. Try getting rid of the  `line-height: 1.75px;` in your `.container_two` and it should fix itself.

Comment: Thank you !!! I knew it wasn't your coding but I was hoping you were able to help and just thank you !!

Comment: @Adrianna Ahh perfect, always happy to help!

Comment: @Adrianna Don't forget to up vote ;) If you have any more questions shoot me a comment!

Comment: I up voted but my level is too low for it to be publicly shown :(